# RHEL 7 security patch installation from tar

Tags: linux, security, rhel7, tar, patch-management

**Novice Linux guy here**

> I have a huge (5G) linux-security-patches tar. Upon extracting, I see its got loads of rpms. What is the most efficient way to install them all ? Also, is it same as installing each rpm individually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RPMs should be with `rpm` or `yum`. If there is no some kind of install script within the tar file, the simplest (and cleanest) way to install all of them in one go with yum:

```
yum localinstall *.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `rpm` & `yum` support wildcards. In RHEL 7 and later `yum` is suggested for rpm packages also - it'll handle dependencies better than rpm.

So issue the command:
`yum install *rpm`

(`yum localinstall` is not needed in RHEL 6 and later)

Still due to the number of RPMs (you mention loads of them) you might face dependency problems; in that case try to install in batches of fewer RPMs. Move some of them to another directory for example and repeat.